# Overriding static method with different static variable in java

Tags: java, static

Suppose I have 3 classes, Animal, Dog, and Cat

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private static final List<Animal> allObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Animal(){
      allObjects.add(this);
    }
    
    // Returns immutable list of all Animal objects
    public static List<? extends Animal> getInstantiatedObjects(){
         return allObjects;
    }
}
```

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    private static final List<Cat> allObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Cat(){
      super();
      allObjects.add(this);
    }
    
    // Returns immutable list of all Cat objects
    public static List<? extends Cat> getInstantiatedObjects(){
         return allObjects;
    } 
}
```

While this works, I can't help but think that this is poor design, and it would be better if either the static method would be inheritable and "adapt" to the class (? extends thisClass), or it raised an implementation error if the method wasn't implemented. For instance,

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private static final List<Dog> allObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Dog(){
      super();
      allObjects.add(this);
    }
    
    /* Returns immutable list of all Dog objects
    public static List<? extends Dog> getInstantiatedObjects(){
         return allObjects;
    } */
}
```

returns no errors and simply uses the static method of the superclass, but that doesn't allow the code to store only objects of its class or lower. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried using an interface, but it won't let me use a static method without a declaration.

Comment: You can't inherit static methods (or really override them). It'd be better to just write `Dog.allObjects.add(this)` specifically, I guess

Comment: I have a question, it really need to be done in each class ? I mean, each class has to have a collection of their instances ? because this problem would be simpler if you used a Singleton with a map of `<Class Type, Collection Of Instances>` don't you think ? I had made my "mini lab" and wow

Comment: Why is it static? Can't a factory maintain those lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From time to time one sees this wish. I never needed it, but the way is to have one global repository in the base class:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private static final Map<Class<? extends Animal>, List<Animal>> all =
            new HashMap<>();

    protected Animal() {
        List<Animal> species = all.computeIfAbsent(getClass(),
                type -> new ArrayList<>());
        species.add(this);
    }

    public static Stream<T extends Animal> all(Class<T> type) {
        return all.computeIfAbsent(getClass(), 
               type -> new ArrayList<>()).stream().map(type::cast);
    }
```

Instead of storing the `Animal` child instance one could use a `WeakReference<Animal>` to let animals disappear when not used.

A call to `Animal.all(Dog.class)` needs no Animal instance.

Answer (score 2):

Do not load your Cat with responsibilities of tracking all cats in the universe. That is way too much for a tiny little feline to handle and it breaks the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Instead implement a cat factory that keeps track of the cats it breeds. Set cat constructor visibility so that it can only be called from the factory method.

```
public class Cat {
    Cat() {
        // Package private prevents construction by unauthorized sources.
    }
}

public class CatFactory {
    public static Cat create() {
        // Instantiate cat, keep record, return.
    }
}
```